# The way we chose/follow or the path we choose or...?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, expressions, sentence-structure

> "the answer to this question will change depending on...
>
> [1] *the way we chose to solve the same issue.*" 
> [or-2] *the way we follow to solve* the same issue."
> [or-3] *the path we choose to solve* the same issue (tense
> issue...)"

Which one of these options (in italic) fits the context best? Notice that I need to keep "we" to show a personal approach.

More context about "the issue": if you believe this you will try to resolve the problem like this, but if you believe that you will try to solve the same problem in a completely different way. (That's why I need to keep "the same" to emphasize that point).

The sentence I'm looking for will repeat this one, but in a slightly different way:

> Depending on the way **we** view the situation, **we** will offer
> radically different approaches to this problem.*
> (So you could see why I need the "we").

The sentence I'm looking for should start like "the answer to this question will change depending on..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to phrase the sentence that will follow the one you gave under *context*.

There are two issues that should be addressed with these phrases:

---

1. The phrase '*same issue*' - are you talking about the issue your answer refers to, the issue that you are currently dealing with in your answer? If yes, I would use the phrase **the issue [at hand](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hand_1)**

> at hand (formal)
>
> c) needing to be dealt with now: Peter turned his attention to the task at hand. (LDOCE)

---

2. The potential mix up of various uses of the nouns *[way](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/way_1)* and *path*

   - they can be used as synonyms meaning:

> *a road, path, direction etc that you take in order to get to a particular place* (LDOCE)

which is **not the meaning you are looking for;**

- *'way'* can be used meaning:

> a method that you use to do or achieve something:

In this sense it is used: *The way to solve/resolve the issue.* As in: *There can be 2 ways to resolve the issue of energy shortage: finding an alternative source or reducing consumption.*

You do not **follow** a way (this is the problem with your option #2). A way that you follow is usually a physical one (*just follow the way until you reach the next crossroad, than turn left*). (!There are exceptions to this, but they don't apply here.)

If there are several ways to do something, you can choose one. Although at first your option #1 sounded a bit ambiguous (*the way we chose* - is it referring to the way that you chose or the choosing strategy you applied?), in this context it is clear what you mean, so this option is fine.

- ['path'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/path) can mean:

> A course of action or way of achieving a specified result
>
> The course or direction in which a person or thing is moving (ODO)

This is often used to describe someones *career path* for example.It is more idiomatic to say that you follow a path than a way in this sense. Again, if there are several possible paths, you choose one of those.

You might say something like:

> The answer to this question will depend on the choice of the path that we would follow to resolve the issue at hand.

While this is a grammatically correct sentence, and there are examples of usage to follow a path in various texts (in social science, physics, law etc.) I am not sure this is the best (most natural sounding) way to put it. That is, it may not be a bad sentence, but it may not be a perfect one either.

---

Having considered all this...

Essentially it seams that your examples convey the same meaning as the sentence you provided in the part you marked as *context*:

The answer to this question = the approaches we will offer

the way we view the situation => the choice of the way/path to solve this problem

way/path = approach

So, unless there is a need to say this twice, the sentence: *Depending on the way we view the situation, we will offer radically different approaches to this problem.* is by far the best one.

Comment: So according to your post it could be "The answer to this question will depend on the choice of the path that we would follow to resolve(/or address?) the same issue" **but** the similar sentence written on my second quote sound more natural for a native. Thank you very (very) much for your help!